# How to change a particular string index

Tags: python-3.6

```
a=(["id': 'tl_00'}"], ["index': '9',"], ["resp': '1110000000001111',"], ["fors': '1110000000001111'}"])
```

I want to create a new list so that all the } are removed

```
a=a=(["id': 'tl_00'}"], ["index': '9',"], ["resp': '1110000000001111',"], ["fors': '1110000000001111'}"])
b=""
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        for k in range(len(a[i][j])):
            b+=a[i][j][k]
            if a[i][j][k]=="}":
                b[i][j][k]+=""
```

The error is list index is out of range. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your 'b' is a string. You can treat a string as a flat list of characters but definitely not as 3 dimensional list. (`b[i][j][k]` <= like tou do here)

Comment: treating it as a three dimensional list gets us to the individual letters

Comment: only true for "a" as it is a tuple of lists of strings. Therefore ` a[i][j][k] ` is a letter. But b is a string as you construct it as one ( `b="" ` ) and you just add individual letters to it..

Comment: true! is there any other way to do this?

Comment: A bit hard to type it out on a phone, but you can do it like this i think: `b=[[string.replace('}','')] for list in a for string in list]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd add an alternative that is closer to your original code:

```
a=(["id': 'tl_00'}"], ["index': '9',"], ["resp': '1110000000001111',"], ["fors': '1110000000001111'}"])
b=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
   b+=[[]]
   for j in range(len(a[i])):
      b[i]+=[""]
      for k in range(len(a[i][j])):
         if a[i][j][k]!="}":
            b[i][j] += a[i][j][k]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.strip()`

**Ex:**

```
a=(["id': 'tl_00'}"], ["index': '9',"], ["resp': '1110000000001111',"], ["fors': '1110000000001111'}"])
b=[[k.strip("}") for k in sublist] for sublist in a]
print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
[["id': 'tl_00'"],
 ["index': '9',"],
 ["resp': '1110000000001111',"],
 ["fors': '1110000000001111'"]]
```